# ¿Cuy y curí son iguales en Colombia?

Tags: hispanoamérica, colombia

Segun [RAE](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=cur%C3%AD), curí se refiere a *Cavia aperea* que segun las fotos en el web parece ser un animal distinto a *Cavia porcellus*, pero segun [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavia_porcellus), Cavia porcellus llevan todos estos nombres:

> , existen varias formas surgidas a partir del nombre onomatopéyico quechua quwi, cuyi, cuyo, cuye, cuilo, cuis. En países del Caribe y Andalucía el nombre presenta variantes como acure, **curí**, curío, cury. En la Sierra Central del Perú Huánuco, Ancash, Pasco, Junín, se le conoce con el nombre de jaca (del vocablo Quechua haka). En Argentina se lo conoce como cuis.

Quiero saber si en Colombia, «curí» sí es igual a «cuy» o se refiere a otro animal (*Cavia* *aperea*). Cuando yo hablaba con un Santandereño una vez de comer «cuy», no me entendió y preguntó si quise decir «curí».

Si son distintos, ¿curí tambien se come o solamente cuy?